# Adding a ComboBox column in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm using an winform datagridview control to add,edit & delete records in an MS Access database. It works great when there is no pk-fk relation. Now I want to add a UserTypeId column in UserDetails table. UserTypeId comes from UserTypes table.

```
Table: UserDetails
--------------------------------------
UserId | UserTypeId | Other fields...|
--------------------------------------
       |            |                |
--------------------------------------

Table: UserTypes
---------------------------
UserTypeId | UserTypeName |
---------------------------
           |              |
---------------------------
```

These are my existing codes-

```
public partial class frmUser : Form
{
    private String connectionString = null;
    private OleDbConnection connection = null;
    private OleDbDataAdapter da = null;
    private OleDbCommandBuilder commandBuilder = null;
    private DataTable dataTable = null;
    private BindingSource bindingSource = null;
    private String selectQueryString = null;

    public frmUser()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmUser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connectionString = GlobalVariables.ConnectionString;// ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"];
        connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM UserDetail";

        connection.Open();

        da = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectQueryString, connection);
        commandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);

        dataTable = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dataTable);
        bindingSource = new BindingSource();
        bindingSource.DataSource = dataTable;

        dataGridViewTrial.DataSource = bindingSource;

        // if you want to hide Identity column
        dataGridViewTrial.Columns[0].Visible = false;
    }

    private void addUpadateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            da.Update(dataTable);
        }
        catch (Exception exceptionObj)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exceptionObj.Message.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void deleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            dataGridViewTrial.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridViewTrial.CurrentRow.Index);
            da.Update(dataTable);
        }
        catch (Exception exceptionObj)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exceptionObj.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

How can i add a look up column using the above code? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you generate the columns in datagridview? if the columns are generated dynamically then you have to make change in your grid and create all columns manually first and assign the database field name in `DataPropertyName` of each DataGridView Column. Now, assign the Column Type `DataGridViewComboboxColumn` to `UserTypeId` column.

After completing all above process you need to populate that column before binding the `DataGridView`.

```
string _SQL = "Select UserTypeId,UserTypeName From UserTypes Order By UserTypeName";
//Dont include Order By UserTypeName if you have created clustered index on it.

SqlDataAdapter Da = New SqlDataAdapter(_SQL, Connection);
DataTable Dt = New DataTable();
Da.Fill(Dt);

DataGridViewComboBoxColumn colUserTypeId = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)DataGridView1.Columns["UserTypeId"];

colUserTypeId.DisplayMember = "UserTypeName";
colUserTypeId.ValueMember = "UserTypeId";

colUserTypeId.DataSource = Dt;

//CODE TO FILL GRIDVIEW
```

Now, your grid will populates User Types in `UserTypeID` column. Application will returns `UserTypeID` from `DataGridView1.Rows[RowIndex].Cells["UserTypeID"].Value` property.

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 `BindingSource`s, one `BindingSource` will be connected to your `UserDetails` table (as you have already done),  while others will be connected to `UserTypes` table.

Then you need to attach that 2nd `BindingSource` with `DataGridView`'s `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`.

```
dataGridViewTrial.DataSource = bindingSource;
// after you are binding your DataGridridView

// assuming that the UserTypeId Column is at 1st index
var colUserTypes = this.dataGridViewTrial.Columns[1];
// by default columns are added as Text columns
// so we are removing the auto added column
this.dataGridViewTrial.Columns.Remove(colUserTypes);

// creating new combobox Column
var cmbColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
cmbColumn.DataPropertyName = "UserTypeId";      // this is the property in UserDetails table
cmbColumn.ValueMember = "UserTypeId";           // this is the property in UserTypes table
cmbColumn.DisplayMember = "UserTypeName";       // again this property is in UserTypes table
cmbColumn.DataSource = userTypesBindingSource;  // this binding source is connected with UserTypes table
this.dataGridViewTrial.Columns.Add(cmbColumn);
```

Normally this thing can more easily be done using design mode. You can search on google I guess there are plenty of aricles availble to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I see this question already has an answer but what if I want to see the list of all the `UserTypes` in that `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` as well ?

We do as Follows:

1. You need 2 separate `Queries` From each `Table`. For the first one we have:

```sql
SELECT UserId, -- cellindex 0
    UserTypeID, -- cellindex 1
    UserTypeID.UserTypeName -- cellindex 2
From UserDetails  
    INNER JOIN UserTypes ON UserDetails.UserTypeID = UserTypes.UserTypeId
Order By UserTypeName
-- WHERE Conditions are applied
```

2. For the second `Query` you will have to do this way:

```sql
SELECT 
    UserTypeId,
    UserTypeName
FROM UserTypes 
-- WHERE CONDITIONS ARE APPLIED
```

3. Now for the next part you are going to use this query to fill your `combobox` items. like the code below:

```cs
// After filling your DataSet with the aforementioned query at part(2) you need to create a column for that
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmbx_clm = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
cmbx_clm.Name = "UserTypesCmbx";
cmbx_clm.HeaderText = "User Types";

// Uncomment the lines below if  you want
//cmbx_clm.HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
//cmbx_clm.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;

// Now Let's bind the cmbx_clm DataSource to the DataSet/DataTable that we named it CreatedDs
cmbx_clm.DataSource = createdDs.Tables[0]; 

// Pay attention to the following lines because it gets tricky
cmbx_clm.ValueMember = "UserTypeId";
cmbx_clm.DisplayMember = "UserTypeName";

// Now let's add the Column to the DataGridView
Users_GRD.Columns.Add(cmbx_clm); // cellindex 3

// For the beauty of our grid we hide the extra column that we do not need
Users_GRD.Columns[2].Visible = false;

// Now in order to show the "UserTypeName" in the combobox and also corresponding to the first query 

foreach(DataGridViewRow row in Users_GRD.Rows)
{
   // We add UserTypeID VALUE to the combobox ValueMember
    row.Cells[3].Value = row.Cells[1].Visible
}
```